# Returning an object vs returning by reference an object

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between

```
vector<int> function(vector<int>& input) {
    // do something with input then return it
    input.push_back(3);
    return input;
}
```

and

```
vector<int>& function(vector<int>& input) {
    // do something with input then return it
    input.push_back(3);
    return input;
}
```

Does it matter? Since when you assign the return of the function to a new variable, the vector gets copied anyways:

```
vector<int>result = function(some_vector);
```

Comment: Yes, it will be copied anyway, but the possibility will be retained if you don't want the vector to be copied such as `function(input).function...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference, the second function can act as lvalue in a statement.

```
function(some_vector).push_back(4);
```

Here the vector is not copied, the original 'some_vector' is modified. Also, performance wise, this may make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using reference as the parameter allows to make return type of the function void

```
void function(vector<int>& input) {
    // do something with input then return it
    input.push_back(3);
    return input;
}
```

By the way member function `push_back` of class `std::vector` has return type `void`.

Returning reference to the vector allows to chain together the function call with other methods of class std::vector. For example

```
function( v ).push_back( value );
```